# Possible to embed portions of Asana into an Iframe or similar?

Tags: iframe, asana

I am in the process of creating a central work page. I am seeking guidance on how to embed Asana components properly into my website. Other services I have consumed provide iframe codes that I can use and I am looking for similar capabilities with Asana.

Comment: Can you give examples of the kind of Asana components you'd want to embed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually go out of our way to make it hard to embed Asana in iframes for security reasons, so no, this is not possible.

(However, I'm curious what it is you would do if you could embed Asana, so we might have a better idea of what we might support in the future)

Comment: We want our users to be able to view their assigned tasks and be able to modify their tasks. We use several services, so creating an intranet with tabs that allows the user to be able to navigate in/out asana quickly. However, just being able to view their assigned tasks would be sufficient enough for now. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: The API allows you to get the tasks for a user with `GET /tasks?workspace=[workspace ID]&assignee=[user ID]` - the results are returned in JSON which is reasonably easy to format to your liking. It's not a drop-in solution, however. Allowing iframes is fairly insecure, I wonder if we could achieve something similar with a script tag widget.

Comment: A widget would be awesome and probably the easiest. I'll accept your response on this ticket for now. Thank you for the detailed input.

Comment: Would be great to be transparent to customers about the tasks we're working on and their statuses.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz - even if you could embed an iframe, if you're not authorized you wouldn't be able to see/manipulate your organization's asana. If you want to be transparent to a specific set of customers, you can always give them guest accounts - if you're talking about throwing open access to your tasks to public, that would require some totally different features to support.

Comment: You could, however, create a public dashboard of some kind using the API.

Comment: @agnoster I wasn't insinuating you literally use an iframe for the solution. I said it would be great to be transparent about the tasks at hand. Asana can build an API that houses read/write permissions to display to an html embed. It could even work with a CLI compiler to output to static HTML...etc.

Comment: @ajkochanowicz ... and if you want to do that, there is in fact an existing API, as I mentioned. You can use it to generate HTML, if you want. My point was that embedding *public-facing* representations of Asana data is an orthogonal issue to embeddability *per se*. What might work with script tags for logged-in customers wouldn't work for showing a public-facing dashboard. I hope that clears it up!

Comment: @agnoster It wasn't unclear to begin with, but it would be great if Asana had a feature behind the "Share" button of a project that let you put in an embeddable feed of the tasks completed/yet to complete in some html instead of telling devs to make and style it themselves with the existing API. Just my feedback.

Comment: Right, but realistically it's not going to happen anytime soon, since that's not really a core use case and we have an infinite number of features we *could* build and finite resources to build them with. Hence: having an API so people can build features that only they need. We'd love to be able to build every feature anyone ever wanted, but it's just not feasible. I hope that knowing that we make it easy to build something like that yourself is a fair compromise. :-)

Comment: Here's a Ruby example with the Asana json api: https://github.com/willjohnson/dashing-asana-tasks